# Use of comma to include or exclude

Tags: commas

In the following:
 The French background check program, in partnership with the French army, is extended to the following:
- All French tennis Technical Officials, National and Above

Does this mean all French tennis technical officials including national and above or does it mean only national and above and exclude all others?

Comment: It’s been a few days now, and there’re no another in coming answer. Trying editing some contexts in your question will make your question active again. And if there was a correct answer for your question, please marked an answer as correct (the green check image) on It.

Comment: What does 'all integers, 3 and above' mean?

Answer (score -1):

The first thing you need to note down is **“does not include”** doesn’t literally equal **”excludes”**.

- **Example: “This price doesn’t include tax”** means you have to add tax to the price before paying.
- **Example: “This price excludes tax”** means you don’t have to pay more than what the price is, in other words, you don’t have to pay tax for this price.

---

**“Above”** means any of particular higher ranks **(however, in the sentence it uses the capital “A” for the word “above”, so it can probably be a name of a department.)**.

---

**“,”** or **comma**, we use it when we have 2 or more items to put on a list before the word **“and”** in order to make it more readable, separating the items.

- **Example: “The list includes red, blue, green, black and blue”**

---

> **“All French tennis Technical Officials, National and Above”**

The **sentence above** means *French tennis Technical Officials, National and any of particular higher ranks/*(a department with the name “Above”) *are on the whitelist.*